# how to replace for loop by forEach

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

My code is,

```java
String Number = "123";
boolean NumberPresent = false;
List < Summary > smryList = smryListResponse.getSummaryList();

for (int i = 0; i < smryList.size(); i++) {
    if (Number.equals(smryList.get(i).getNumber())) {
        NumberPresent = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (NumberPresent) {
   //perform some actions
}
```

How can I replace this complete `for loop` functionality with `forEach`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is clearly a homework assignment and you should show us what you have attempted first.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/

Comment: Yeah, looks like a homework problem.  I suppose the first question for original poster is: "Tell me in once sentence what this code is doing."

Comment: @David Brossard : I know how to replace for loop with foreach, but my current functionality is having break statement too. I wanted to know how can we use break with foreach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `for` or `forEach` if you want to detect is number presented. You can use streams with i.e. `.anyMatch()` method.
In example:

```java
String number = "123";    
List<Summary> smryList = smryListResponse.getSummaryList();
boolean isNumberPresent = smryList
                           .stream()
                           .anyMatch(summary -> summary.getNumber().equals(number));
if (isNumberPresent) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, you can try do that with other stream methods, i.e. `.filter()` or other. But I prefer to use `.anyMatch()`.

> **Remark:** streams and lambda expressions works only with **Java 8** or **later**.
> Otherwise use already posted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64494386/5272951)

Answer (score 5):

this way you  can apply for-each loop.

```java
for (Summary summary: smryList) {
    if (Number.equals(summary.getNumber())) {
        NumberPresent = true;
        break;
    }
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the for loop with this loop.

```
 for (Summary summary : smryList) {
            if (Number.equals(summary.getNumber())) {
                NumberPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

otherwise, you can try

```
smryList.forEach(summary -> {//code here
        });
```